# Tender Methods Through API

Tags: square-connect

When I use V1 List_Payments the tender type doesn't show all of the credit card options. It just says MANUAL for example on a chip.

I am trying to get all of these payment methods. How do I show each of these payment types?

Card - Swiped
Card - Tapped (Contactless)
Card - Dipped (Chip)
Card - Keyed
Card on File
Card - Other
Cash
Gift Card
Other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently with the V1 List_Payments the available [Tender.EntryMethod's](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#enum-tenderentrymethod) are MANUAL, SCANNED, SQUARE_CASH, SQUARE_WALLET, SWIPED, WEB_FORM, and OTHER.

Unfortunately Card - Swiped Card - Tapped (Contactless) Card - Dipped (Chip) Card - Keyed Card on File Card - Other Cash Gift Card Other isn't currently available.

Comment: Hi Bryan, so there isn’t any way to pull this information at all?

Comment: Hi Armando, right there isn's currently any way to get the information.

Comment: Hi Bryan, is there any plans for the future to add it?

Comment: Hey Armando, currently Square doesn't have any public road maps as to when and if features will become available.

Comment: Thank you Bryan for your help! It was really most appreciated.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Do you know if there has been any change to issue?

Answer (score 0):

With our Orders API you can now get entry_method which includes the following:

SWIPED
The card was swiped through a Square reader or Square stand.

KEYED
The card information was keyed manually into Square Point of Sale or a Square-hosted web form.

EMV
The card was processed via EMV with a Square reader.

ON_FILE
The buyer's card details were already on file with Square.

CONTACTLESS
The card was processed via a contactless (i.e., NFC) transaction with a Square reader.

You will still need to look to "tenders" "types" for :

CASH
Cash.

SQUARE_GIFT_CARD
A Square gift card.

NO_SALE
This tender represents the register being opened for a "no sale" event.

OTHER
A form of tender that does not match any other value. 
https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/search-orders